# UIImageView size doesn't update until out of sight

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying to make an image 100% the height of the cell, but it doesn't seem to update correctly.

I have created a special `getCellHeightFromData` method that is meant to calculate the height from the text length. I also have a method called `getRestaurantPictureById` that downloads an image from a web server which responds with an image resized to the specific width and height, and returns it as an `UIImage`.

I want to set the `UIImageView` to the same width and height as the image that was loaded. I have access to both the width and height as float numbers, so that is not the problem.

#### The UIImageView outlet looks like this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Thumbnail;
```

#### My attempt at resizing the image (from inside my UITableViewCell subclass)

```
- (void)updateCellWithContent:(RestaurantCell*)restaurant
{
    self.NameLabel.text = [restaurant name];
    
    float width = 75.0;
    float height = [RestaurantCell getCellHeightFromData:restaurant];
    
    self.Thumbnail.frame = CGRectMake(self.Thumbnail.frame.origin.x, self.Thumbnail.frame.origin.y, width, height);
    self.Thumbnail.image = [DataLoader getRestaurantPictureById:restaurant.restaurantId withWidth:width andHeight:height];
}
```

It does not look correctly immediately when I run, but if I scroll so that a cell goes out of sight, and then let it bounce back, it has been redrawn with the proper (100%) height.

#### Before scrolling out of sight

[image: Before]

#### After scrolling the first cell out of sight and letting it bounce back

[image]

**Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go select your `UIimage`,
2. afterwards go to show the attributes inspector and find mode.
3. Select Top left.

Have an awesome day.

Comment: For some reason, that actually fixed it! Very strange solution, but thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and ensure it returns the right value. Then, wherever you set the cell height (e.g. in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) , you can just call this method to get the height value. Basically, you want to ensure you have a single value for each row's height, and not several.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my `updateCellWithContent` method is called from the heightForRowAtIndexPath already, I'm aware of that.